# .exe created in Visual Studio 2012 does nothing on another computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I've created a simple application in Visual Studio 2012 that plays media, and am now trying to run that application on another computer (as a side note, I am using WMPLIB and also Krypton Toolkit in this app). It runs fine when I run it out of Visual Studio or from the .exe file in the /Debug folder, but when I try and run it on another computer, it does absolutely nothing. I've tried creating a release version (which did not create an .exe in the /Release folder) and also tried using Dependency Walker to check the DLL's needed (there were far too many for me to comprehend) but nothing seems to work. Any idea what could be preventing the application from running?

Comment: I'm not completely sure about this, but are you sending the lib with the program? Does your friend have .net framework installed? (just shootin' in the dark here...)

Comment: Is it crashes on another computer? Any error messages?

Comment: Is there an error message when building the release version? It should create the exe in /Release folder unless you changed the configuration

Comment: @Zachrip I'm not sure what you mean by "sending the lib". And it popped up with a .NET installer when it first ran on my other comp

Comment: @x2 It doesn't crash, it just does nothing. It shows the waiting cursor, then the cursor changes back to the normal one and nothing appears.

Comment: What is the OS of your computer and the other computer?

Comment: @Martheen the computer it was made on was Windows 7 32-bit, and the computer I'm trying to run it on is Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: @QuinnMillir I'm not sure if it's part of windows, I'm asking if you're sending the library with the program if it isn't?

Comment: do you see the process running in the taskmanager, is your project compiled for .NET 4.5 and does the other computer have .NET 4.5 installed ? Are you using any icons in your application which are not copied properly ?

Comment: What is the CPU configuration? If it's in AnyCPU, try change it to x86, sometimes the app in AnyCPU will try to load 64 bit library when running in 64 bit OS, and it will crash (maybe silently) if there's no 64 bit version available

Comment: Just for a quick test, can you try running it in compatability mode? (I'm really not all that sure this will work, but if the program runs then, you probably know the problem)

Comment: @Zachrip I ran it in Compatibility mode, and it did the same thing as before (nothing).

Comment: @Vignesh.N the taskmanager shows nothing, and it installed the needed version of .NET when I first ran it. As for the icons, all the icons that I used are in a Resource file, so unless that is not included in the .exe file, they should be in there

Comment: @Martheen I'm unsure how to actually change that property. I'm in the VIEW/Property Pages/Build section, and it won't display anything other than AnyCPU. Is there another place I should be changing it?

Comment: It's in Project Properties. Either in Debug, Project, Solution or Build menu depending or your version and layout

Comment: Also, try delete everything in debug folder, then rebuild your project, and copy everything in debug folder to your other computer.

Comment: Recompile your program after subscribing to the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx] Inside the handler include `MessageBox.Show()` to show the exception. Also make sure you are not suppressing any exceptions in your try{}catch{} blocks.

Comment: @Martheen I found the setting and changed it, but there was no difference. The thing that is confusing me is that if I remove the /debug folder out of all the visual studio files and run it somewhere else on the computer, it runs fine. Does that mean that I need to install something on the other computer for it to work?

Comment: Shouldn't be.. Since WMPLIB is Windows standard library (except when you get N version or manually uninstall them yourself) and Krypton Toolkit will be distributed along your Debug folder. How you call WMPLib? Did you directly refer to it's location by literal string or via System.Environment?

Comment: @Martheen I also removed all the files in the debug section one by one until the program would not run anymore, and the only 2 things required are the ZxInterop.WMPLib.dll and Interop.WMPLib.dll

Comment: @Martheen I checked where the reference to the AxInterop.WMPLib went to, and it's a direct path to the .dll in the /debug folder. How would I make it so that it's not a direct path?

Comment: Try copy the AxInterop to another folder outside, than remove the reference, and re-add the reference from that outside folder. However, this might not be the solution since you already tried running the app form another folder. At least, now the Release configuration should work

Comment: About removing the file, actually I want you to just remove everything in debug folder, and then rebuild to ensure all referenced dll will be copied automatically back to the debug folder

Comment: @Martheen yes, I have removed all files in the debug folder and re-built it (still didn't work). One question, should I be working out of the Debug folder in /bin? or the one in /obj. I've been dealing with /bin thus far.

Comment: obj isn't meant to be run directly. Can you build in Release mode and use the Release folder result?

Comment: @Martheen that's one problem that I've been having, it won't output anything until in the Release folder of /bin. I'm doing this: imgur.com/nyGnxO3 to set it to debug, which is what I've read to do online. Is this wrong?

Comment: @QuinnMillir That's exactly the way to do it. So when you set it to Release mode, what's written in the Output window?

Comment: Have you switch the target platform from AnyCPU to x86?

Comment: Can you please update the question with all the answers from comments, as it merely impossible to follow this discussion in comments?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to deliver the Krypton.toolkit.dll with the exe file, Or use ilmerge to add it to the exe.